# Forward wildcard e-mail address to a single e-mail address?

Tags: email, forwarding

I am running a .com domain, like www.mydomain.com.

I have the support address at support@mydomain.com, but my clients usually send e-mails to the support staff emails (e.g. *johndoe@mydomain.com*) and not to *support@mydomain.com*.
Since those old unique e-mail addresses are no longer needed, I'd like to forward **@mydomain.com* to *support@mydomain.com*. Is it possible?

I know I can redirect **specific** values to *support@mydomain.com*, but they're around ~50, so I was wondering if there is any way to use wildcards.

I only have basic knowledge of cPanel. I tried searching and found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/115144/sendmail-forward-wildcard-mx-to-a-single-email-address), but I can't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Whicn MTA?  Sendmil?  Postfix?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you apparently use cPanel:

catch-all adresses can be set in /etc/valiases/*mydomain.com*

add a line

```
*: support@mydomain.com
```

that being said, I really don't recommend adding a catch-all address. chances are high you'll get a lot more spam. It's usually better just to just educate your clients and tell them to use the correct support address. This will also save you much time in future migrations of your mail system.

Comment: I thought of the spam option, but my clients keep and keep on doing the same. I even posted a red alert on my webpage, but they still do the same (most of them). Instead of dealing with so much e-mails, I prefer to get them all on my support e-mail.

About the /etc/ issue: I'm on a shared hosting (though paid and good, I can't get a VPS yet) and I can't edit that file. However, my cPanel shows that I have infinite configurable e-mail forwards, so is there any way to do the same without access to that file?

Comment: if you have a "default address" option in your mail section in cPanel you can set it there. but nowadays afaik most hosters disable this option. if you can't find it there you'll probably have to ask your hoster to set it.

Comment: Thanks, I found the default address option, and it works. It resends every e-mail to *@mydomain.com to support@mydomain.com, and it still sends foobar@mydomain.com to Foo Bar and not to support.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, turn on wildcard but direct it to problem@maydomain.com. It will get lots of spam, but for the legitimate emails and domains you can whitelist to trigger a response that says "that address is no longer valid, please email support@maydomain.com." Once a day or so (or later once a week) you can update the whitelist. I'll bet that cleans up your mess fairly quickly.

Also, you need to set your system or mail clients such that if a rep replies to a message in the support queue, the default reply address they send is support@mydomain.com - not the rep's address.  That should prevent this mess in the future.